# Get the value of an input field within multiple divs when clicking a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html

How would I go about correctly writing this so that the **var input** is the value of the **content** input field within the .overlay div when the submit button is pressed? Keep in mind that there's several .overlay divs, so it needs to be that separate div.

I know how to make it work assuming only 1 div exists, but this isn't the case. My jQuery is as follows:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
      var input = $(this).parents('.overlay')$(input[name=content]).val();
});
```

My HTML structure (assume this div is duplicated several times on the page):

```
<div class="overlay">
      <input name="content" value="value">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
      var input = $(this).parent().find("input[name='content']").val();
});
```

should work.

Or, if you can rely on that exact structure:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
      var input = $(this).prev().val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
      var input_val = $(this).parent().find('input:first').val();
    alert(input_val)
});
```

here is ia [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wGPef/)